# Kong Ingress cert-manager wrong routing

Tags: kubernetes, kong, cert-manager, kong-ingress

I have a k8s cluster with kong-ingress and cert-manager.

- `Backend` at: `domain.network/*`

To renew the certificate, cert-manager starts a new pod and ingress which should reply at:

- `CertManagerHandler` at: `domain.network/.well-known/xxx/zzz`

However, when trying to access the well-known route, `Backend` handles the request, not `CertManagerHandler`

I think it might come from the `*` in the path of `Backend` but I'm not sure.

[image: ingress]

I defined `Backend` ingress with:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

...

http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
```

How to make the .well-known endpoint to be handled by the cert-manager pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by removing the wildcard from the path:

- `/*` to `/`

Did the trick.